# Sharing user between two apps when one is a system app

Tags: java, android, permissions

I found many references to shared user IDs among two apps and it looks like what I'm looking for.

What I'm concerned about is that there are statements like permissions will be shared between the apps. If one of the apps is a system app, does that mean that the normal app will have system privileges too?

I want one app to be a regular app and one app to be a system one. I don't want the regular app to have any of the system admin privileges.

We are doing this so we can share a Content Provider. Our data is on the edge of being complicated enough for this, but I feel it's justified.

Comment: A process will only ever have the privileges of the user which runs it, whatever the OS. Therefore your question is not clear. Can you define your needs more precisely? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Why do you need a shared user ID?  If it's merely to share data, you should probably look at other means of authenticated interchange.

Comment: @ChrisStratton How about now?

Comment: You don't need a shared user id to interchange data with a content provider.

Comment: @ChrisStratton am I mistaken in that this will make our interactions more secure; because I can disable the ability of everyone else to get to it.

Comment: It is very unclear what you want, really; for one, a "system user" as you call it will only ever have extended clearance over the data stored _on the local system_; by no means using such an account is a guarantee of elevated prvileges on some remote resource. At this point I suggest you just rethink your problem.

Comment: @fge I have modified my question. It is undesirable for my normal app to have system admin privileges. I want to make sure they don't.

Comment: @fge - the question context is Android, where each app typically runs in a sandbox formed by having a unique unix user id, and where many capabilities of the device are exposed by *local* cross-user IPC services, either within Android itself or added by 3rd party app packages.  The question concerns the interaction between the special mechanism which can let two distinct apps sharing the same signing certificate be joined under the same user id with a common sandbox, vs the fact that apps installed on the system partition can have permissions which apps installed on the data partition cannot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this is something you can't do. If you set up your system app as shared, you don't get any kind of an error, but Android appears to refuse to acknowledge it.

I took shared back out of my manifest file and it is working fine now.

Live and learn...